# Acceder a Display Name de un parametro en un informe

Tags: ireport, pentaho

Tengo un parámetro en mi informe en el que le asigno un valor que en este caso es 01 y un display name que es lo que va a mostrar en el combo. por ejemplo "Primera Empresa" De esta forma el parámetro queda así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema esta en que cuando yo quiero pintar el valor de ese parámetro seleccionado en el informe, lo que me pinta es el value no la columna name.

No me vale de mucho ver en el informe por ejemplo 001  sino la columna display name asignada.

He intentado poner código pero no hay código que poner, como mucho puedo poner la foto del parámetro para que se entienda bien, estoy leyendo pero no encuentro nada a este respecto.

Muchas gracias

Espero que se me haya entendido.

Comment: Entiendo que lo que buscas es algo como lo que se indica en esta página: [Pentaho Report Designer: How to show the parameter display name in your report when it is different from the parameter value](https://diethardsteiner.blogspot.com/2013/05/pentaho-report-designer-how-to-show.html). Espero el idioma no sea un problema para ti. No publico una respuesta porque no tengo Pentaho Reporter instalado y no puedo hacer las pruebas necesarias. Sin embargo, entiendo tu situación y me parece que allí se indica la solución. Saludos

Comment: Si, has entendido perfectamente y me han sido de gran ayuda el post. SI no te importa,  pon el comentario como una respuesta para poder darte la recompensa que tenia ( Ya ha caducado..)

Comment: Lo de la recompensa no hace falta. Te invito a responder tu propia pregunta, para que ayudes a otros que tengan el mismo problema. Pasadas 24 horas de que publiques tu respuesta, puedes aceptarla como válida. Como te comenté desde un principio, no tengo forma de probar la solución, en cambio tu ya lo has hecho y eso es un plus. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Como ha publicado  el compañero Mauricio, en este enlace se explica perfectamente como acceder al valor del parámetro mediante una query y la función SINGLEVALUEQUERY.

Simplemente se pone en el campo default value  formula del parámetro la función  `=SINGLEVALUEQUERY("nombreQuery")` que tomará el valor resultante de la query.
A esta query le pasamos como parámetro el código del objeto del que queremos obtener el valor.

La query será del tipo `select name from miTabla where cod= ${miParam}`

Viene bien explicado en el siguiente enlace.

https://diethardsteiner.blogspot.com/2013/05/pentaho-report-designer-how-to-show.html